# How to add default class to first child in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-props, vuejs-slots

I have a Tabs component:

```
<template>
    <div class="tabs">
        <div class="tabs__list">
            <div
                class="tabs__tab"
                :class="{'tabs__tab_active': i === active}"
                @click="changeTab(i)"
                v-for="(label, i) in Tabs.labels"
                :key="i"
            >{{label}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="tabs__container" ref="container">
            <div class="tabs__wrapper" ref="wrapper">
                <slot />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    computed: {
        active() {
            return this.Tabs.active
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            Tabs: {
                labels: [],
                items: [],
                active: 0
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setHeight() {
            const el = this.Tabs.items[this.active]
            const height = el.scrollHeight
            this.$refs.container.style.height = height + 'px'
        },
        scrollWrapper() {
            const {wrapper} = this.$refs
            const offset = 100 * this.active
            wrapper.style.transform = `translate3d(-${offset}%, 0, 0)`
        },
        changeTab(i) {
            this.Tabs.active = i
            this.setHeight()
            this.scrollWrapper()
        }
    },
    provide() {
        return {
            Tabs: this.Tabs
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.setHeight()
        this.scrollWrapper()
        this.debounce = _.debounce(this.setHeight, 50)
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.debounce)
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.debounce)
    }
}
</script>
```

And it has a child component Tab and I am making an API call to get the products. Each product has variations and each variations have name. This is how I am displaying:

```
<div class="tabs-content">
                            <Tabs v-for="variation in product.attributes.variations">
                                <Tab :label="variation.name" :active="false">
                                </Tab>
                            </Tabs>
                        </div>
```

But here the problem is all Tab component has a class of 'tabs__tab_active'. But as a default, I only want first child. So do you have any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are already pulling the index out of the other for loop. You should be able to use that to add a conditional class

```
<Tabs v-for="(variation, index) in product.attributes.variations">
  <Tab :label="variation.name" :active="false" :class="{'tabs__tab_active': index === 0}">
  </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `tabs` component

```
<div class="tabs__list">
            <div
                v-for="(label, i) in Tabs.labels"
                :key="i"
                :class="['tabs__tab', {'tabs__tab_active': i === 0}]" // change added
                @click="changeTab(i)"
            >{{label}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited my question. I am getting error like in the picture.

Comment: this line `this.debounce = _.debounce(this.setHeight, 50)` inside mounted is giving the `_ is not defined` error

Comment: also in my answer its `:key="i"` and not `:key="I"`